# verbal offer and I accepted but no written offer yet

Tags: job-offer

Hello Yesterday I received a verbal offer for a job and I accepted.  I was given the salary, the start date and all the information needed. I was told that I would have the written offer emailed to me by the end of business today via email and I have not received it. I was wondering if I still got the job?

Comment: No one here can answer that.  Only the company you applied to.  Most likely the HR department is just moving a bit slow.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for a day or two and if you still do not receive a written offer, call your contact at the new company and ask. In any case, do not inform your current employer or give notice until you have a written offer in hand.